# Orphan not removed

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

In Symfony 2.3, a Member entity is not deleted as expected. The data show that the Member record remains with `household_id` null. Something obvious eluding me?

#### Household entity includes

```
/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Member", mappedBy="household", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=true)
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"dob" = "ASC"})
 * @Assert\Valid
 */
protected $members;

/**
 * Remove members
 *
 * @param \Mana\ClientBundle\Entity\Member $members
 */
public function removeMember(Member $member) {
    $this->members->removeElement($member);
    $member->setHousehold(null);
}
```

Comment: There may be contexts in which the orphanremoval is not locked for example in preupdate event listener, how the entity is removed?
An alternative can be to set the cascade at the database level with onDelete="CASCADE" in joincolumn definition.

Comment: @KernelFolla: Cascading at the db level is not available - the table is MyISAM to enable a FULLTEXT search.  The application has no added event listeners.

Comment: ok I suppose you remove the entity with $em->remove($entity)
try to add fetch="EAGER" to the column definition and check the mapping with octrine:schema:validate command.
And remove $member->setHousehold(null); from removeMember(), you don't need it

Comment: @ KernelFolla: Please provide the above as an answer so I can accept it! It took `fetch="EAGER"` to remove the orphan. `$member->setHousehold(null);` was indeed superfluous.

Comment: @KernelFolla: Resend of comment, this time without the intrusive space. Please provide the above as an answer so I can accept it! It took `fetch="EAGER"` to remove the orphan. `$member->setHousehold(null);` was indeed superfluous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the handler for orphanremoval does not work if the collection is not initialized.

I'm not sure it's an issue of doctrine but you can workaround the problem adding `fetch="EAGER"` to the column definition.

Comment: Curious, though, since `$this->members = new ArrayCollection();` exists in Household `__construct()`.

Comment: Yes but when doctrine create an entity it is replaced with PersistentCollection and it is not initialized until you take other entity from the collection.